# How to find the next parent object from a child Jquery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, javascript

So consider this:

```
<div id='parent'>
   <div id='child1'>
   <div id='child2'>
</div>
<div id='parent2'>
</div>
```

I know that from #child1 I can use .next() to get #child2... but can I use something like .nextparent() to go from #child2 to #parent2?

I know the .nextparent() this is ridiculous but I can't figure out how to do this.

regards,
taylor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#child1').parent().next()
```

Try that.

Comment: fantastic thank you! That is very useful. Ill accept when it lets me.